# How limit acces to my local web site with apache

Tags: django, apache, local-network

i want limit acces to my django local web site with apache , I succeeded restricted the access to the website ip / phpmyadmin, but when I put the IP:8000/ the website work !! ,  how to blocked access to be last

Comment: Use a firewall or listen to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0. Also using something like nginx for external connections and blocking all other incoming connections works well.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but if you want to restrict access to port 80 to only localhost try changing `Listen` flag in your httpd.conf to

`Listen 127.0.0.1:80`

Or

`Listen localhost:80`

It wont allow other systems in your network to access your web server.

There are couple of ways but this one is simple.

**edit**

```
<Directory /your/path/to/home>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order deny, allow
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    deny from 192.168.0.1` # comma separated ip list here
</Directory>
```

Comment: i have local web site  192.168.1.5:8000/home , i want limit acces to this url  for spefic ip